# Installing R package itself on Github actions

Tags: github-actions, r-package

How to install an R package itself (based on the version that triggered the action), in the GitHub actions, before starting running the rcmdcheck?

Comment: Same question but for a different purpose - to then knit an RMarkdown doc

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the R package itself. Add this section to `Installing dependencies` section of your workflow.

```
 - name: Install dependencies
     run: |
         remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
         remotes::install_cran("rcmdcheck")
         remotes::install_cran("devtools")
         devtools::install()
     shell: Rscript {0}
```